# Array to String After Two Elements

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1 
    [1] => 0 
    [2] => 0.32593699614063 
    [3] => -0.010875407736967 
    [4] => 0.32593699614063 
    [5] => 0.325936996140630.32593699614063 
    [6] => 0.1135301278 
    [7] => -0.028758634562 
    [8] => 0.044068247856859 
    [9] => -0.028758634562 
    [10] => 0 
    [11] => -0.01759558330449 
    [12] => 0 
    [13] => 0 
    [14] => 0 
    [15] => 0.05005732991382 
    [16] => 0.17093532486612 
    [17] => 0.098872325264 
    [18] => 0.346220929 
    [19] => 0.098872325264 
    [20] => 0.38405017865388 
    [21] => 0.098872325264 
    [22] => 0.64744282045057 
    [23] => 0.098872325264 
    [24] => 1 
    [25] => 0 
)
```

I need to convert it to the following `string`:

```
1 0, 0.32593699614063 -0.010875407736967, 0.32593699614063 0.32593699614063, etc.
```

In other words, there should be a comma after every two elements.

Can you suggest the `php` code? Currently I have `string` without commas after every two elements.

**Code:**

```
$od = array_flatten($MultiDimensional)
$result = implode(" ",$od);
```

**Output:**

```
1 0 0.32593699614063 -0.010875407736967 0.32593699614063 -0.028758634562 0.1135301278 -0.028758634562 0.044068247856859
```

Comment: Could you format it please?

Comment: Need formatting, https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk` with `implode`

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$res= '';
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 2) as $key => $value){
  $res .= ($key < count(array_chunk($arr, 2))-1) ? (implode(' ',$value).",") : implode(' ',$value); 
}
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/U7lAW)

Comment: @Learner you can accept the answer if it resolved your concern

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `array_chunk`, `array_map` and `implode` :

```
$od = array(1, 0, 0.32593699614063, -0.010875407736967, 0.32593699614063, -0.028758634562, 0.1135301278, -0.028758634562, 0.044068247856859);

echo implode(',' , // each pair is separated by a comma
    array_map(function($pair){return implode(' ', $pair);}, // each element in pair separated by a space
              array_chunk($od, 2) // cut original array in blocks of 2 items
    )
);
```